# Button redirects the wrong form in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I've created a program where there is a section of user comments and a section where you can type a comment if you are logged in.

If you are logged in, any comment that you have written has a delete button that redirects you to a seperate php page called "deletecomment.php" that handles deleting comments.

There is also a button for submitting a comment, in a different form with a different action that should take you to "comment.php" which handles submitting comments.

My problem is that the form with action "comment.php" redirects you to "deletecomment.php" instead. But since they are two seperate forms with two seperate buttons this should not happen.

Why does the second form redirect me to "deletecomment.php" instead of "comment.php"

```
<div class="textblock">
                <h1>User Comments</h1>
    <ul id="usercomment">
        <li>
            <?php foreach($readin as $string):?>
        <div>
    <form action="deletecomment.php" method="post">
        <?php if($count%2==1): ?>
                <?php $readin_copy = $readin;
                echo current($readin_copy);?>
             - <?php  echo $string?> 
                    <?php if($string===$_SESSION['username']):?> 
            <button type="submit">Delete comment</button> 
        <input name='delcomment' type='hidden' value= "<?php echo current($readin_copy);?>">
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $count++;?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
            </div>
        <br />
            <div class="textblock">
        <ul>
         <?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']==true):?>
        <li><form action="comment.php" method="post"> <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" name="comment" required> <button type="submit">Enter Comment</button></form>
        </li>
        <?php endif;?>
        </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please add comment.php and deletecomment.php pages as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had made an error with the if statements, the else ifs and endifs should be inside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other codes on the file? Do you have an isset function that deals with which button was clicked?

Where are you storing your comments?

For every submit button, name it as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Comment"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment"/>
```

And after that, write in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    header("Location: deletecomment.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("Location: comment.php");
}
```

However, I am still confused where you are storing your new and old comments. Are you doing this with MySQL?